# how to find the lengh of the input in an array and match pattern in perl

Tags: perl

i am new to to the perl scripting
   i have an array like this 
   my @array (0x0B,0x04,0x02767,0x0000,0xffffaf)
   my expected output:
   if the length of the index is more than 4(i have assumed 0x0B=4) then do 
   the split and join the string like this
   0x2767-->0x27,0x67
   0xffffaf->0xff,0xff,0xaf

here i am trying to find out the length of the input string and matching 
   pattern if the length of the input string  is more than 2 and match the
   pattern then it should be satisfy the if condition

```
my $input = "0x0B";
# Name of the file the data is in
my $input_filename  = 'my_input_original.txt';
```

# Name of the file you want to dump the output to
   my $output_filename = 'my_org_output.txt';

# Open the file
   open my $input_fh, "<", $input_filename or die $!;

# Open the output file
    open my $output_fh, ">", $output_filename or die $!; to
     my $output_filename = 'my_org_output.txt'
     my updated code what i want to do

```
here is what i want to do
my input data:
total_sum   0x0B    Uint8,unsigned char     
num     0x0C    Uint8,unsigned char     
max     0x4A    Uint8,unsigned char     
padd    0x00     Uint8,unsigned char        
ideal   0x01    Uint16, unsigned short      
newtext{2}  { 0x00, 0x00 }  Uint8,unsigned char     
my_new  0x02     Uint16, unsigned short     
newtest2{2} { 0x00, 0x00 }  Uint8,unsigned char     
xyz         0x0A     Uint8,unsigned char        
newtest4{3} { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char
gtotal 0xffffffaf   Sint8,signed char
info    0x2767  Uint16, unsigned short
my_output:

0x0B,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,
0x00,0x00,0x0A,0x00,0x00,0x00

1.if the line contain Uint16 then pad with 0x00 with the value

2.if the line contain the value with 0x2767 split and join 
 with(e.g.0x2767->0x27,0x67) or 
 0xffffaf (0xffffaf->0xff,0xff,0xaf)
my code :
#here is extracting only hex value
while ($_ =~ m/(0x(\d+)(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi)
{
 push @hex_array, $1; # here i get only hex value of for my input data
 #here if the array contain index value more than two then i need to
 #split the data and join also if the line contain Uint16 then i need to 
 #padd with 0x00 before the value (for e.g. 0x04-->0x00,0x04)
  foreach my $element (@hex_array) 
    {
   my @parts;
  if (4 < length $element) 
   {
    pos $element = 2;  # skip 0x
    @hex_array = map "0x$_", $element =~ /../g;
 } else 
 {
    @hex_array = $element;
 }
}
}
# Write the data to the file
print {$output_fh} join("U, ", @hex_array);
please help me
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The length (=number of elements) of an array is returned in scalar context, i.e. a simple `my $len = @array;` will do. // The `length` function returns the length of a _string_, so `length('foo')` gives `3`. // `0x0B` as a hex number is actually 11 in decimal. However, the _length_ of the _string_ `0x0B` is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a bunch of 32-bit values as hex, and that you want to pack them into the specified big-endian type, and that you want a hex representation of the packed structure.

(Note that this assumes you are wrong about the output for `gtotal`. If I understand correctly, `0xffffffaf` means `-81`, which is `0xAF` as a `Sint8`.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my %packers = (
   Uint8  => sub { pack 'C*',  @_ },
   Sint8  => sub { pack 'c*',  @_ },
   Uint16 => sub { pack 'S>*', @_ },
   Sint16 => sub { pack 's>*', @_ },
   Uint32 => sub { pack 'L>*', @_ },
   Sint32 => sub { pack 'l>*', @_ },
);

my $packed = '';

while (<DATA>) {
   my ($vals, $type);
   if (/^\S+ \s+ \{ \s* ( 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ (?: \s* , \s* 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ )* ) \s* \} \s+ ([^\s,]+) /x) {
      $vals = $1;
      $type = $2;
   }
   elsif (/^\S+ \s+ ( 0x[0-9a-fA-F]+ )\s+ ([^\s,]+) /x) {
      $vals = $1;
      $type = $2;
   }
   else {
      die("Unrecognized syntax at line $.\n");
   }

   my @vals =
       map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ }  # Convert to number and fix the sign
          split /\s*,\s*/,
             $vals;

   my $packer = $packers{$type}
      or die("Unsupported type \"$type\"\n");

   $packed .= $packer->(@vals);
}

# say sprintf '%v02X', $packed;

say
   join ',',
      map { sprintf("0x%02X", $_) }
         unpack 'C*',
            $packed;

__DATA__
total_sum   0x0B    Uint8,unsigned char
num     0x0C    Uint8,unsigned char
max     0x4A    Uint8,unsigned char
padd    0x00     Uint8,unsigned char
ideal   0x01    Uint16, unsigned short
newtext{2}  { 0x00, 0x00 }  Uint8,unsigned char
my_new  0x02     Uint16, unsigned short
newtest2{2} { 0x00, 0x00 }  Uint8,unsigned char
xyz         0x0A     Uint8,unsigned char
newtest4{3} { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char
gtotal 0xffffffaf   Sint8,signed char
info    0x2767  Uint16, unsigned short
```

Output:

```
0x0B,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x0A,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xAF,0x27,0x67
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.when i  have added  my input file then i am   getting  this error  "  Unrecognized syntax at line 1 " but if i add the input data ( which is i have given only few lines) then its work fine.

Comment: i have debug the issue and i had found Sint16,Uint32 and Sint32 all these three type does not exist in my file then i tried to change the this line from map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ } to  map { unpack 'c', pack 'c', hex $_ } getting error Use of uninitialized value $vals ,$type and Use of uninitialized value $type in concatenation (.) or string how to fix this issue ?

Comment: please ignore my above comments ,i have found the issue i was giving space in the beginning of the line and if the line start with1.non_tcs_adding_newcell (my_new_max = (0x00), padd1{3} = ({ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }))
2.new_st[0] then the above code not working

Comment: Again, I gotta ask what's your point? Is there a question you want to ask? Is it even on topic? I showed you how to do the conversions (and even went *way* beyond that to help you), so I consider the matter closed unless you have a question about the conversions. If you need help parsing other lines, I expect to see effort

Comment: i don't now how to do conversation i am sorry please don't block my account .

Comment: No, no,  there'll be no blocking of accounts. If you have a new question,  simply ask a new question. There are chat rooms, but SO is all about questions and answers

Comment: please help me to understand your solution..looks like i wont able to ask new question due to some account related issue ..Thanks

Comment: There's very little to it. /// The regex matches extra the desired information from the input. /// `unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_` takes the hex of the 32-bit number (e.g. `0x0B`, `0xffffffaf`) and convert its to the number it represents (11, -81). /// The packers convert the number into the desired format.

Comment: I want to understand more about the regex pattern matching 
then want to modify the regex for matching following three properties

basically present code does not match all these three condition.

1.if the line start with some header--> then it should igonre
2.myinfo_st[0]-->then it should igonre
3.non_my_info (non_t_max = (0x00), padd1{3} = ({ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 })) -->then it should extract hex value

I dont know whether i should asked in comments or raise new question
if possible please help me..Thanks

Comment: The regex pattern is rather trivial. What part do you not understand? /// As for your new question about parsing, it's unreadable, it doesn't demonstrate any effort whatsoever, and it's posted as a comment instead of a question. I already told you I wouldn't answer it in comments!

Answer (score 2):

The "index" of an array element is usualy the number, not the element itself. 
`=~` is the binding operator, I doubt you want to create a regex from a length of a numeric comparison.
But I guess you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @array = qw( 0x0B 0x04 0x02767 0x0000 0xffffaf );
for my $element (@array) {
    my @parts;
    if (4 < length $element) {
        pos $element = 2;  # skip 0x
        @parts = map "0x$_", $element =~ /../g;
    } else {
        @parts = $element;
    }
    say join ', ', @parts;
}
```

I.e. if the element is longer than 4 characters, get pairs of its characters except the first one, prepend `0x` to them, and output.

The code might be simplified if you don't mind burning some CPU cycles on removing `0x` from the short inputs and putting it back:

```
my @array = qw( 0x0B 0x04 0x02767 0x0000 0xffffaf );
for my $element (@array) {
    pos $element = 2;  # skip 0x
    my @parts = map "0x$_", $element =~ /../g;
    say join ', ', @parts;
}
```

Comment: Apparently I must improve my capabilities as a clairvoyant to keep up with you. ;-)

Comment: 0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020x000x000x0A0x000x000x000x040x000x000x040x050x000x001f0x001f0x007f0x , i have input like this now i need to place comma for each of length 4(i.e 0x0B,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x01)

Comment: i was doing my@array=0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020x000x000x0A0x000x000x000x04‌​0x000x000x040x050x00‌​0x001f0x001f0x007f0x then unpack("(A2)*", @array); but it did not work

Comment: @Ria: You've changed the question significantly, making it even less clear than before. Use a new question to ask a new question.