# Perl:How to convert array of integer into one byte

Tags: perl

```
my @array= 0xffffffffffffffdf,0x2347,0x2360,0x2365,0xffffffffffffffcf,0x00,0x4a
```

I have an array of 1 byte ,2 byte and 8 byte of data.
The 2 and 8 byte of data in the array will be coming at random place

1. I want to split 2 byte of array into each of 1 byte  for e.g.(`0x2347` ---> `0x23,0x47`)
2. I want to truncate 8 byte of signed data  into 1 byte for e.g.(`0xffffffffffffffcf` ---> `0xcf`)

my_code:

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;      
  my@array="0xffffffffffffffdf,0x2347,0x2360,0x2365,
             0xffffffffffffffcf,0x00,0x4a";
  my @split_array;
  my @new_array;
  foreach my $index (@array) 
  {
  my @split_array;

  if (length $index >4) 
  {

    @split_array = map "0x$_", $index =~ /../g;
  } 
  elsif (length $index>16) 
  {     
   @split_array = map "0x$_", $index =~ /../g;       
  }
  else 
  {
    @split_array = $index;
  }
  @new_array=join(", ", @split_array);
  }
  print "@new_array\n";
```

my code output:

0x0x, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xdf, 0x,0, 0xx2, 0x34, 0x7,, 0x0x, 0x23, 0x60, 0x,0, 0xx2, 0x36, 0x5,, 0x0x, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xcf, 0x,0, 0xx0, 0x0,, 0x0x, 0x4a  0x0x, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xcf

Expected output:

```
0xdf,0x23,0x47,0x23,0x60,0x23,0x65,0xcf,0x00,0x4a
```

please suggest me steps with explanation..?

Comment: Have a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html   
and 
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works. If you show us what you have tried and explain what problems you are having ,then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Down voted question because no effort shown. Seems more like a "do this for me" question rather than "I am stuck". Post what you have tried, even if it looks horrible and does not work, at least everyone can see you have tried.

Comment: @Gerry I have written the code and I will mention what is wrong with the output. Will be shortly adding the code.

Comment: Please do, then just edit the original question with the code.

Comment: Actually length should be 6 (0x1234) when I check with 6 I am getting output as input but when I check with 4 at least I could see some variations in my output. why its not taking length as 6 ?

Comment: That's not your code. That code doesn't even compile (`use stricts`, for example!) And why do people think they can write good code with such random indentation?

Comment: @DaveCross I have corrected the spelling for (use strict)

Comment: @ShreyasNGowda: Thanks. But that's not really the point. You should be pasting in the exact code that you're using. Anything else is a waste of our time as we have to correct typos like that which you have already fixed. Is this now your real code? Does your `@array` really only contain a single element?

Comment: @DaveCross this is the same code that I am using and its working for me and I am getting same output as I have mentioned in my output

Comment: Well, changing `my @array = "..."` to `my @array = (...)` would be a good start!

Comment: The team of [Ria](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6871400/ria), [abhishek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6839106/abhishek) and [Shreyas N Gowda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7080014/shreyas-n-gowda) have asked this question multiple times before. They have been told they have insufficient inputs to achieve the desired output, but they keep asking why their code doesn't work. I would mark this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40132199/589924, but I do not want to do so unilaterally.

Comment: @Dave Cross, They've been told to use `push @array, hex($1);` instead of `$str .= $1;` in the only reasonable question this team has asked, but they have consistently ignored this.

Answer (score 2):

You want -33 (`0xffffffffffffffdf`) to become `df` (the bytes of it stored as a signed 8-bit integer).

You want 9031 (`0x2347`) to become `23 47` (the bytes of it stored as a big-endian unsigned 16-bit integer).

As such, in addition to the value, you also need to provide the type into which the value should be converted (e.g. `Uint16`). **You are lacking this necessary information.**

Two of the other answers try to work around this problem by guessing at the type, converting values less than 256 into a single byte of output. However, [data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39678809/589924) previously provided by your team show that `"0x02"` could just as likely need to be converted into `0x00,0x02` as `0x02`.

So, as one of your teammates has previously been [told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136392/589924), **you can't achieve the desired result from the information you provided.** For example, to get the output you desire, you'd need

```
my @data = (
    [ 'Sint8',  '0xffffffffffffffdf' ],
    [ 'Uint16', '0x2347' ],
    [ 'Uint16', '0x2360' ],
    [ 'Uint16', '0x2365' ],
    [ 'Sint8',  '0xffffffffffffffcf' ],
    [ 'Sint8',  '0x00' ],
    [ 'Sint8',  '0x4a' ],
);
```

Once you have that, you can use the previously posted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682057/589924).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw( portable );
use feature qw( say );

my %packers = (
   Uint8  => sub { pack 'C*',  @_ },
   Sint8  => sub { pack 'c*',  @_ },
   Uint16 => sub { pack 'S>*', @_ },
   Sint16 => sub { pack 's>*', @_ },
   Uint32 => sub { pack 'L>*', @_ },
   Sint32 => sub { pack 'l>*', @_ },
);

my $packed = '';
for (@data) {
   my ($type, $hex) = @$_;

   # Convert to number (and fix sign).
   my $val = unpack 'q', pack 'q', hex $hex;

   my $packer = $packers{$type}
      or die("Unsupported type \"$type\"\n");

   $packed .= $packer->($val);
}

say
   join ',',
      map { sprintf("0x%02x", $_) }
         unpack 'C*',
            $packed;
```

Output: (Exactly as expected)

```
0xdf,0x23,0x47,0x23,0x60,0x23,0x65,0xcf,0x00,0x4a
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your program

You should at least `print` the value of `$index` each time it changes

Here are some observations

- Please at least tidy and indent your code properly before asking for help. It is rude of you to throw out stuff like that and ask for a fix
- Your `@array` (apart from having and awful name -- the `@` already says that it's an array, so the `array` part is worthless) contains *only one element*, which is an 82-character string with a newline and spaces in the middle
- You use a `for` loop which executes once to assign that string to a variable `$index` (again, a dreadful name -- array indexes are integers that start at zero)
- You test first for whether the length of the string is > 4. This test will always succeed first, even for strings that are longer than 16 characters and should be handled by the second test. Remember though that you have *one string*, which is 82 characters long
- Note that, even if if you manage to set `$index` to `0xffffffffffffffdf`, it will stringify to something like `1.84467440737096e+19`, which won't be much use if you just treat every pair of characters as hex digits

Comment: I agree what you said could please help me how to approaches this problem

Comment: You need to explain where your data is coming from

Answer (score 0):

```
map {($_ & 0xffffffffffff0000) ? ($_ & 0xff) : (($_ & 0xff00) >> 8, ($_ & 0xff))} @array;
```

map is the keyword to iterate over an array. It allows to produce more items as output than was present in input.

To identify a 8 byte data from a 2 byte data, I have used a mask. If bits are set outside the low 16 bits, it means it is a 8 byte data.

To split the two bytes data, I have also used masks.

Comment: I have input of one byte as well sorry that I have not added before in my code

Comment: I have tried this I am getting some error Argument "0xffffffffffffffdf,0x2347,0x2360,0x2365,0xffffffffffffff..." isn't numeric in bitwise and (&)

Comment: @ShreyasNGowda: That's because your `@array` contains a single item which is "0xffffffffffffffdf,0x2347,0x2360,0x2365,0xffffffffffffffcf,0x00,0x4a". You need to define your array properly (as explained in one of my previous comments).

Comment: Fails when `0x0012` is a Uint16 (which is definitely possible based on past questions by this team). You can't use heuristics; extra information is needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @input_hex = (0xffffffffffffffdf,0x2347,0x2360,0x2365,
                 0xffffffffffffffcf,0x00,0x4a);

my @output_hex;

for (@input_hex) {
  if ($_ > 0xffff) {
    push @output_hex, ($_ & 0xff);
  } elsif ($_ > 0xff) {
    push @output_hex, ($_ & 0xff00) >> 8, ($_ & 0xff);
  } else {
    push @output_hex, $_;
  }
}

say join ',', map { sprintf '0x%02x', $_ } @output_hex;
```

I'm going to put as much effort into explaining my answer as you put into explaining your question - i.e. none.

Comment: Fails when `0x0012` is a Uint16 (which is definitely possible based on past questions by this team). You can't use heuristics; extra information is needed to solve this problem.