# error while extracting both value and type from lines

Tags: perl

This question was asked by me earlier 
[how to find the lengh of the input in an array and match pattern in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678809/how-to-find-the-lengh-of-the-input-in-an-array-and-match-pattern-in-perl/39682057?noredirect=1#comment66755031_39682057)

Here my input is in decimal format later converting to hex

> 1.While extracting type I am getting compilation error

```
" Global symbol "$type" requires explicit package name at test15.pl line 65."
" Global symbol "$type" requires explicit package name at test15.pl line 66."
```

> 2.When I have checked the output of vals and type (by commenting last few
>     lines of the code from my $vals= to $packed)
>     I am getting both values and type as I have mentioned below

```
 0x01,uint8
 1440,Uint16
 0xbb3,Uint16
 ffffffbf,Sint8
 0xa3,uint32
```

> 3.My regex not able to extract values from middle of lines

```
For e.g.
rrc_mac_interface   RLC_PDU { 1}    rrc_mac_interface   #default   type is uint8
gsm_lte_interface   scell + ncell + gsm cell { 3}   gsm_lte_interface   #default   type is uint8
reserved_for_data{3}    { 0, 0, 0 } Uint8,unsigned char
```

> my input lines:

```
trans_id    1   uint8,unsigned char
Pdu_size    5120    Uint16, unsigned short  
sub_sfn         2995        Uint16, unsigned short
rrc_mac_interface   RLC_PDU { 1}    rrc_mac_interface   #default type is uint8
gsm_lte_interface   scell + ncell + gsm cell { 3}   gsm_lte_interface   
#default type is uint8
minvalue         -65    Sint8,signed char 
numtrx           163     uint32,unsigned short 
reserved_for_data{3}    { 0, 0, 0 } Uint8,unsigned char
my_st[1]      0         //do not match if the this line has []
```

> code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
my $inputfile  = 'input.txt';
my $outputfile = 'output.txt';
open my $my_ipfh, "<", $inputfile or die $!;
open my $my_opfh, ">", $outputfile or die $!;

my %packers = (
Uint8  => sub { pack 'C*',  @_ },
Sint8  => sub { pack 'c*',  @_ },
Uint16 => sub { pack 'S>*', @_ },
Sint16 => sub { pack 's>*', @_ },
Uint32 => sub { pack 'L>*', @_ },
Sint32 => sub { pack 'l>*', @_ },
);

 my $packed = '';
 while (<$my_ipfh>)
 {      
 if (/([+-]?\d+)\s+ (uint8|sint8|Uint8|Sint8|uint16|sint16|Uint16|Sint16|uint32|sint32|Uint32|Uint32)/xg)
  {
    my ($vals, $type);
    $vals =$1;
    $vals =sprintf("0x%02x", $1);
    $type =$2;
    print "$vals,$type\n";
  }
    my @vals =
    map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ }  # Convert to number and fix the sign   
    my $packer = $packers {$type} 
    or die("Unsupported type \"$type\"\n");  #error in this line
    $packed .= $packer->(@vals);

    say
    join ',',
     map { sprintf("0x%02X", $_) }
     unpack 'C*',
        $packed;
 }
```

> some mistakes I am doing which I am not able to catch if somebody can help me would be great ?

Comment: The line `map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ }` continues with `my $packer=…`. The `map` misses its second parameter (some list).

Comment: `$type` is declared inside the `if` block so it cannot be seen or used outside that block (scope). Put the declaration of `$type` outside the `if` and be prepared that it only gets set (to a reasonable value) when the `if` condition matches.

Comment: @PerlDuck  Thanks those two error are gone but i am  getting new error                                                                                                   1.Use of uninitialized value $_ in hex at test15.pl line map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ } <$my_ipfh> line 1.
2.Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at test15.pl line $packed .= $packer->(@vals), <$my_ipfh> line 1.
3.Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at test15.p

Comment: Sorry. [so] is not meant to be an interactive debugging service. If you have further questions, feel free to post them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked a bunch of questions. I'll cover one.

> *While extracting type I am getting compilation error*

`my` declares a lexical variable. It exists only for the block it's in.

```
if( ...whatever... ) {
    my $something = 42;
}

print $something;
```

This is different from, say, Javascript where `var` is scoped to the whole function no matter where you declare it.

`$something` does not exist outside that `if` block. When `use strict` is on, Perl does not allow you to use undeclared variables, so that print statement will produce an error at compile time.

[Read more about scoping in Perl here](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/05-perl-functions.html#U2NvcGU).

This is why it's *very important* to get your indentation right. Being able to clearly and quickly see scopes is one of the most important things in programming. Your code is poorly spaced and indented. Here's how it should look.

```
my $int_type_re = qr{
    ( [+-]? \d+ )
    \s+
    ( [us]int(?:8|16|32) )
}xi;

my $packed = '';
while (<$my_ipfh>) {
    if ( $_ =~ m{$int_type_re} ) {
        my ($vals, $type);
        $vals =$1;
        $vals =sprintf("0x%02x", $1);
        $type =$2;
        print "$vals,$type\n";
    }
    my @vals =
      map { unpack 'l', pack 'l', hex $_ };

    my $packer = $packers {$type} 
      or die("Unsupported type \"$type\"\n");  #error in this line

    $packed .= $packer->(@vals);
}
```

With proper 4 character indentation and good use of blank lines, it's much clearer what's inside the `while` loop, what's inside the `if` and what's a multi-line statement.

I've also moved the complicated regex out of the condition and into its own variable. This both gives it a name to help understand what it's doing, and it makes the condition easier to read.

I made use of the `/x` regex modifier and newlines to space the regex out clearly. Then, with it pulled apart into smaller pieces, I saw I could collapse the repeated parts.

I also removed the `/g` regex modifier because it wasn't doing anything. That's for looping through multiple matches in a single string like:

```
while( $x =~ /(\w+)/g ) {
    print "Word is $1\n";
}
```

Or in list context:

```
my @words = $x =~ /(\w+)/g;
```

Comment: @Schwem in this line g need to removed " if ( $_ =~ m{$int_type_re}) "otherwise it will through compilation error

Comment: @Ria The syntax error isn't the `/g`, it's the semi-colon. Your original regex had a `/g` on it, so I retained it, though I see now it wasn't doing anything so it should be removed.

Comment: @Schwem thanks for your valuable input my present regex not able to match some of the lines any help please ?